# What can I do to eliminate the unsafePerformIO in this Reflex.Dom code?

Tags: haskell, reflex

```
main = mainWidget $
  el "div" $ do
    let fileInputConfig = FileInputConfig (constDyn Map.empty)
    fi <- fileInput fileInputConfig

    let uploads   :: Dynamic t [File]            = value fi
    upload        :: Dynamic t (Maybe File)      <- (return . fmap headMay) uploads
    getNameAction :: Dynamic t (Maybe (IO Text)) <- (return . fmap (getNameText <$>)) upload
    filename      :: Dynamic t (Maybe Text)      <- (return . fmap (unsafePerformIO <$>)) getNameAction

    el "div" $ dynText (show <$> filename)
  return ()
  where getNameText :: MonadIO m => File -> m Text
        getNameText = getName
```

I did my best to play connect-the-dots with the types but I couldn't find a path out without using `unsafePerformIO`.  I think it's safe in this case, but obviously there are other similar things you might want to do that would not be safe.

Comment: You've got to get that `IO` to the outer layer of `Dynamic t (Maybe (IO Text))` so you can bind it.  `sequenceA` is the general way to commute an applicative outward, e.g. `sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`, i.e. `sequenceA :: Maybe (IO a) -> IO (Maybe a)`.  But that would require `Dynamic t` to be traversable, and I don't know if it is.

Comment: sequenceA does get the IO to the outside (ie I end up with a `Dynamic t (IO (Maybe Text))`) but I'm still unsure how turn that into a `Dynamic t (Maybe Text)` without `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: Yeah, what is `Dynamic t`, what library are you working with?

Comment: Reflex/Reflex.Dom (as mentioned in the title).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For things like this, you usually need `performEvent`. I don't have compiler/REPL at hand to provide more detail, and the function is sort-of hidden behind some typeclass hackery (https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/blob/9575a5660334fb8a617da1cd9aa1b522e8e4ddb7/src/Reflex/PerformEvent/Class.hs), but the gist of it is that if you have an event carrying `IO`, then you can run it wherever this event occurs.

Now, you've got the `Dynamic`, but you can

- extract the event from it
- maybe it doesn't need to be Dynamic (it doesn't make sense, as you don't want to peek at the `IO` value)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into `performEvent` now.